# Does anybody know the name of this system monitor application?

Tags: applet

Does anybody know the name of this system monitor application?

[image]

Comment: Looks like conky: http://conky.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

It's conky, an system monitor for clients based in the X server. You can find more information in http://conky.sourceforge.net/.

It also can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install conky
```